# Convert AVPlayer NSData to NSString (Or player format)

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I need to know how to convert saved NSData from an AVPlayer back into a playable format. But I cannot figure out how to convert this NSData into a dataString, which would then allow me to create and NSUrl. Let's say I have the following code:

```
    NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    self.data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
```

Now later on when I get this data back, I call:

```
    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.data bytes]];
```

But the dataString is always nil. Why? Am I decoding it in the wrong format or something?

Answer (score 0):

A URL is a reference to data. The data is a (possibly complicated) encoding of something like a movie.

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but I think you want to get the data (as an NSData object) and then save it somewhere. If this is correct, then what you need to do is

```
[self.data writeToFile:myFilePath atomically:YES]
```

where myFilePath is a path to somewhere where you can store files.

Comment: Why can't I do this?    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]; 
        //Now that you have a string, you can create an NSURL
        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; Saving it to a file is not something I want to do. I don't want to the downloaded data to be that permanent. This was my attempt to play the data without saving it to a file.

Comment: There are two primary reasons why I do not want to save to a file: Saving much data dynamically to the device seems like it would be prone to filling up device space, and secondly, it forces me to automatically create path strings to save the data, since there are many downloaded videos.

Comment: A URL is a reference to a file somewhere. URLWithString takes a string like "http://www.apple.com" not data. If I was dong this, I would use temporary files to store the video data. I am not sure why you resist that approach. If you really want to avoid the file system, you can probably subclass AVAsset.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to provide data for `AVPlayer`.

```
func resourceLoader(resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader!, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest!) -> Bool {
    if let data = videoData {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            if let infoRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest {
                infoRequest.contentType = "public.mpeg-4" // UTI
                infoRequest.contentLength = Int64(data.length)
                infoRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = true
            }
            if let request = loadingRequest.dataRequest {
                let part = data.subdataWithRange(NSRange(location: Int(request.requestedOffset), length: Int(request.requestedLength)))
                request.respondWithData(part)
            }
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

To create an `AVPlayer`:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(scheme: "yourcustomscheme", host: nil, path: "/pathtovideo"), options: nil)
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```